# Rendering dynamic scss-files with ajax, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, dynamic, sass

As the title suggests, my main objective is to render a dynamic scss(.erb) file after an ajax call.

**assets/javascripts/header.js**

```
// onChange of a checkbox, a database boolean field should be toggled via AJAX
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input[class=collection_cb]').change(function() {

    // get the id of the item
    var collection_id = $(this).parent().attr("data-collection-id");
    // show a loading animation
    $("#coll-loading").removeClass("vhidden");

    // AJAX call
    $.ajax({
      type    : 'PUT',
      url      : "/collections/" + collection_id + "/toggle",
      success : function() {
        // removal of loading animation, a bit delayed, as it would be too fast otherwise
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#coll_loading").addClass("vhidden");
        }, 300);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

**controller/collections_controller.rb**

```
def toggle
  # safety measure to check if the user changes his collection
  if current_user.id == Collection.find(params[:id]).user_id
    collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

    # toggle the collection
    collection.toggle! :auto_add_item
  else
    # redirect the user to error page, alert page
  end

  render :nothing => true
end
```

All worked very smooth when I solely toggled the database object.

Now I wanted to add some extra spices and change the CSS of my 50+ `li's` accordingly to the currently selected collections of the user.

My **desired CSS** looks like this, it checks li elements if they belong to the collections and give them a border color if so.

```
ul#list > li[data-collections~='8'][data-collections~='2']
{
  border-color: #ff2900;
}
```

I added this to my controller to generate the `[]-conditions`:

```
def toggle
  # .
  # .
  # toggle function

  # return the currently selected collection ids in the [data-collections]-format
  @active_collections = ""
  c_ids = current_user.collections.where(:auto_add_item => true).pluck('collections.id')
  if c_ids.size != 0
    c_ids.each { |id| @active_collections += "[data-collections~='#{id}']" }
  end

  # this is what gets retrieved
  # @active_collections => [data-collections~='8'][data-collections~='2']
end
```

now I need a way to put those brackets in a scss file that gets generated dynamically.

I tried adding:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.css
end
```

to my controller, having the file **views/collections/toggle.css.erb**

```
ul#list<%= raw active_collections %> > li<%= raw active_collections %> {
  border-color: #ff2900;
}
```

It didn't work, another way was rendering the css file from my controller, and then passing it to a view as described by [Manuel Meurer](https://gist.github.com/manuelmeurer/6399889)

Did I mess up with the file names? Like using `css` instead of `scss`? Do you have any ideas how I should proceed?

Thanks for your help!

**Why dynamic CSS? - reasoning**

I know that this should normally happen by adding classes via JavaScript. My reasoning to why I need a dynamic css is that when the user decides to change the selected collections, he does this very concentrated. Something like 4 calls in 3 seconds, then a 5 minutes pause, then 5 calls in 4 seconds. The JavaScript would simply take too long to loop through the 50+ `li's` after every call.

## UPDATE

As it turns out, JavaScript was very fast at handling my "long" list... Thanks y'all for pointing out the errors in my thinking!

Comment: I don't understand why such need for dynamic CSS. Why not using static CSS and switching the div's class by jQuery, that's plain simple.

Comment: If you want to load dynamic CSS file I think you have to use javascript to append `<link rel>` element thingy to your HTML page. But as @BillyChan said there is no need to go that far… If you want to apply styling based on certain condition then use javascript. If that style going to apply to multiple elements then insert the style on `head` element of your page.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and I would be on your side normally, why I wanted to use CSS rather than JavaScript is that my `ul` can have 50+ `li's`. Going through them all after every little toggle would make my app superslow...

Comment: Looping through 50 elements in JS is not going to be that slow at least not slower than another HTTP request.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I will try the JS solution again, maybe I messed it up last time, I'll be giving you guys some results tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem you've got isn't to do with CSS; it's to do with how your system works

CSS is loaded static (from the http request), which means when the page is rendered, it will not update if you change the CSS files on the server

JS is client side and is designed to interact with rendered HTML elements (through the DOM). This means that JS by its nature is dynamic, and is why we can use it with technologies like Ajax to change parts of the page

Here's where I think your problem comes in...

Your JS call is not reloading the page, which means the CSS stays static. There is currently no way to reload the CSS and have them render without refreshing (sending an HTTP request). This means that any updating you do with JS will have to include per-loaded CSS

As per the comments to your OP, you should really look at updating the classes of your list elements. If you use something like this it should work instantaneously:

```
$('li').addClass('new');
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Hey Rich! I really appreciate your help! As it turns out, there was a problem with my system / my thinking. I found a nice JS solution that works perfectly as predicted! :)

I really have to roll the dice between you and Billy who'll get the bounty...

Comment: This tool chose you, use my rep wisely ^^, http://www.miniwebtool.com/random-name-picker/

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the rep! Haha nice choice! I'll see if I can set a bounty on a question for Billy

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your feature correctly, actually all you need can be realized by JavaScript simply, no need for any hack.

Let me organize your feature at first

- Given an user visiting the page
- When he checks a checkbox
- He will see a loading sign which implies this is an interaction with server
- When the loading sign stopped
- He will see the row(or 'li") he checked has a border which implies his action has been accepted by server

Then comes the solution. *For readability I will simplify your loading sign code into named functions instead of real code.*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[class=collection_cb]').change(function() {

    // Use a variable to store parent of current scope for using later
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    // get the id of the item
    var collection_id = $parent.attr("data-collection-id");

    show_loading_sign();

    // AJAX call
    $.ajax({
      type    : 'PUT',
      url      : "/collections/" + collection_id + "/toggle",
      success : function() {
        // This is the effect you need.
        $parent.addClass('green_color_border');
      },
      error: function() {
        $parent.addClass('red_color_border');
      },
      complete: function() {
        close_loading_sign(); /*Close the sign no matter success or error*/
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Let me know if my understanding of feature is correct and if this could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What if, when the user toggles a collection selection, you use jquery change *one* class on the `ul` and then define static styles based on that?

For example, your original markup might be:

```
ul#list.no_selection
  li.collection8.collection2
  li.collection1
```

And your css would have, statically:

```
ul.collection1 li.collection1,
ul.collection2 li.collection2,
...
ul.collection8 li.collection8 {
  border-color: #ff2900;
}
```

So by default, there wouldn't be a border. But if the user selects collection 8, your jquery would do:

```
$('ul#list').addClass('collection8')
```

and voila, border around the `li` that's in `collection8`-- without looping over all the `li`s in javascript and without loading a stylesheet dynamically.

What do you think, would this work in your case?

Comment: Thanks Carol for you help, this is smart thinking :) The static CSS  didn't work for me as a li could have many different collections.